# Experiencing gcc 5 failure running poetry install on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, python3, gcc

Multiple error: `command 'gcc-5' failed: No such file or directory..`

gcc version: 9.3
poetry version: 1.1.4
python: 3.9.1
Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: `poetry install` install the packages defined in your project. Please include the specific package that causes the issue, because it’s impossible to guess from your question for now.

Answer (score 7):

The fix I found was to just do this

```
ln -s /bin/gcc /bin/gcc-5
```

```
    
$ ln -s /bin/gcc /bin/gcc-5
$ pip3 install netifaces
Collecting netifaces
  Using cached netifaces-0.10.9.tar.gz (28 kB)
Using legacy 'setup.py install' for netifaces, since package 'wheel' is not installed.
Installing collected packages: netifaces
    Running setup.py install for netifaces ... done
Successfully installed netifaces-0.10.9
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thank you!  I was pulling my hair out on this one as a very deep downstream dependency of one of my packages in Poetry is apparently hardcoded to reference `gcc-5`.

Comment: This fixed it for me, although in my case I had to do ln -s /usr/bin/gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5

Answer (score 2):

Don't use gcc-5, that causes ubuntu to specifically look for GCC 5.x, which is years out of date and not installed on most systems.  Just use 'gcc' as the command, which will delegate to the default, installed gcc version (in your case, 9.3).

If you're following a guide that tells you to run a script, find a new guide or edit the script.